# Foreign cluster not bootstrapping from local cluster

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I'm trying to test database replication with 2 instances of MarkLogic (one on host machine, one on guest VM, both Windows).
I've clustered both instances successfully, but when trying to configure the database replication (host as Master, guest as Replica), it fails with the following error:

```
There was a problem in setting up Database Replication.

Foreign cluster has not bootstrapped from local cluster
```

Trying to set up the replication from the guest, I can't get to the configuration screen, being met with:

```
No databases retrieved from foreign cluster.
```

I've checked that the host and guest can communicate properly (would have to, to initialise the cluster).

Any ideas on what the issue might be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a simple firewall issue. I thought'd I has disabled Windows Firewall on the host machine for this connection - I had not.